# Regex to evaluate a list of 6 digit numbers separated by commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field that I would like users to put in a list of numbers that are 6 digits long.  the list the users input will have variable lengths.

**Pass**

123456, 123457, 156545, 546541, 546541

**Pass**

123456, 123457

**Pass**

546541

**Fail**

12345, 155154

**Fail**

154s54, 159475, 153456

**Fail**

154s544, 159475, 153456

Comment: How far did you get, where did you get stuck? What went wrong? What did your attempt do wrong, what did it not do that it should have done? What does it do that it shouldn't?

Comment: This is question is basically "give me the codz".  Is it a homework question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regEx you are looking for is /^\d{6}$/, which matches a 6 digit number and only 6 digit number.

```js
var cases = [
  '123456, 123457, 156545, 546541, 546541',
  '123456, 123457',
  '546541',
  '12345, 155154',
  '154s54, 159475',
  '154s544, 159475, 153456'
];
//Break up numbers in string into array the check each token
//against the regex.  If all tokens passes the test, then it
//returns true, else false.
t = cases.map(c => c.split(', ')
         .reduce((p, n) => p && !!n.match(/^\d{6}$/), true));
for (let i=0; i < cases.length;i++)
console.log('case:', cases[i], t[i]?'pass':'fail');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not looking to capture the individual numbers, but just want to validate the input, the following regex should do:

```
^(\d{6},\s*)*\d{6}$
```

Breakdown of the regex:

- ^ beginning of the string
- (\d{6},\s*)* zero or more occurrences of a 6-digit number, followed by a comma and optional whitespace
- \d{6} a 6-digit number (this is the last and possibly the only one)
- $ end of the string

Note that the expression enclosed within parentheses is a capture group. To avoid capture and make it stricter the expression would be written as:

```
^(?:\d{6},\s*)*\d{6}$
```

Note the `?:` after the first parenthesis. It means match the expression but do not capture it.